# Symfony2 set user role default User and Role files

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a problem with storing user role into database. I´m using original files written  here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

and here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html

logging in a logging out is working. I can save user into database, but I don´t know how to save his role. Is it possible with this files, or I have to do one more file which will be serving this alone? I don´t want to use FOSUser Bundle ...  Thank you for your answers. Here are links:

AccountController
 http://pastebin.com/ycrLyUcg

Registration
 http://pastebin.com/Q7se6pnF

RegistrationType
 http://pastebin.com/926tu0hj

User
 http://pastebin.com/aNdQr46C
Role
 http://pastebin.com/cg7QTk59
UserRepository
 http://pastebin.com/LHPuy4We

Thank you very much for your answers

EDIT 10.11.2013 23:00:

- http://pastebin.com/DDygxzDN   AccountController.php
- http://pastebin.com/SmSJMm4t   User.php
- http://pastebin.com/fEZk7JPa   UserRole.php

EDIT 11.11.2013 15:20

- http://pastebin.com/Zu8w7cQ9   Role.php

Comment: What does the user model you're persisting look like? You may just need to map a role field to the model so that it can be persisted, and set the role on the user before you persist it.

Comment: I thought, that it is mapped. It is used for logging in. so how should i do it?

Comment: How do you mean it? Which files?

Comment: Sorry, deleted my above comment; Is the second link (entity provider) representative of your user model?

Comment: First two links are tutorials, which I used. I forgot to post user, role and userrepository. I will add it into my question. Edit: added the links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem was solved. I used files from this tutorial: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html. And than I had to do this:

> $ php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
>
> $ php app/console doctrine:database:create
>
> $ php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
>
> $ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
>
> $ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate

Thank you Sean Quinn

Comment: Glad I could help get you to the right place, even if my solution wasn't the exact one you needed! :)

Answer (score 8):

In your AccountController's `createAction` method you're never actually assigning a `Role` to the user; you'll have to set that first before you can use it as part of your authentication processes. Something like this should persist the `Role` given your above model.

```
if ($registrationForm->isValid()) {
    ...
    $role = new Role();
    $role->setName('User');
    $role->setRole('ROLE_USER');

    $roles = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
    $roles->add($role);

    $user->setRoles($roles);
    ...
}
```

Also, I would reconsider the requirement of having a `@ManyToMany` relationship between **Users** and **Roles**, `@ManyToOne` is probably sufficient here; regardless if you wish to stick with any sort of association mapping you will probably need to make sure that when you persist the `User` class that the associated roles are also persisted. To do that, you may need to add a `cascade` instruction to your `User` class, like so:

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"all"})
     */
    private $roles;

    ...
}
```

The default `User` class in `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User` also uses a collection of roles for its user objects, so once you have the role(s) persisting you may be able to just use the existing [UsernameAuthenticationProvider](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php), hopefully everything will just work. If it doesn't you may have to customize the authentication provider.

Notice that in the above we're explicitly assigning the `$roles` property with the `setRoles()` method; this is because the return type of `getRoles()` is not the `ArrayCollection`, but the primitive `array`. If you want everything to "just work" with Symfony's existing authentication provider having `getRoles()` return the primitive array is correct as far as I can tell.

---

#### A New Look at the Same Problem (11/10/2013):

> "*I did it as you wrote, but it is trying to wrote in into acme_roles table, where I save role types - admin, user .... but I want to save the role of user into user_roles table - I save there user id and role id*"

Given what you've indicated that you want in the extended comments in the chat my approach would be to use three entities/tables to model your user-to-role relationships. This is obviously only one way to approach the problem.

Your tables would be : `acme_users` (`User` entity), `acme_roles` (`Role` entity), and `acme_user_roles` (`UserRole` entity).

- Your `User` would not have a many-to-many relationship directly with your `Role` objects, instead you can have a **one-to-many** relationship between the `User` and a `UserRole` class.
- The association class, `UserRole` (or whatever you call it), needs a primary key (`id`) and two many-to-one relations: one for the `User` and one for the `Role`.
- There is no need to create an inverse relationship between the `Role` class and the `UserRole`, because your roles live in isolation to the rest of the entities.
- Before assigning a `Role` to your newly created `User` you need to look it up first, once you have found it you can create your `UserRole` with a reference to your `$user` and `$role` and then add that to your set of roles on the `User` class.

The above is just a rough outline of how you can approach the problem; in more detail:

1. Your `User` class should map a relationship to the `UserRole` entity via a `@ORM\OneToMany` annotation, e.g.:

   ```
       /**
        * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", mappedBy="user", cascade={"all"})
        */
       private $userRoles;
   ```
2. In `User`, change your `getRoles()` method to return the actual roles associated with the `UserRoles`, similar to:

   ```
       /**
        * @inheritDoc
        */
       public function getRoles()
       {
           $roles = array();
           foreach ($this->userRoles as $userRole) {
               $roles[] = $userRole->getRole();
           }
           return $roles;
       }
   ```
3. In `User` class, add `getUserRoles()`, `setUserRoles()` (and possibly an `addUserRole()`) methods, remove `setRoles()`
4. In `UserRole`, you want to store entity references not ID's (they will be mapped as IDs in the columns any way, due to Doctrine), so just change `$user_id` and `$role_id` to `$user` and `$role` respectively, and alter their mappings (also if you want multiple roles to be assignable via the `UserRole` association, you need to have a discrete identity/primary key, so add the `$id` property) like so:

   ```
       /**
        * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
        * @ORM\Id
        * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        */
       private $id;

       /** 
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userRoles", cascade={"all"})
        */
       private $user;

       /**
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Role", cascade={"all"})
        */
       private $role;
   ```
5. Remove all references to `$users` from your `Role` class.
6. In the `AccoundController`, lookup the Role you want to assign (i.e. if you want to assign the `ROLE_USER` look up the correct and corresponding role), and assign it to your `UserRole`, then assign your `UserRole` to your `User`, finally persist your `$user`, e.g.:

   ```
   $user = $registration->getUser();
   $user->setSalt($this->generateSalt());
   $user->setIsActive(1);

   $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
   $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
   $password = $encoder->encodePassword($user->getPassword(), $user->getSalt());

   $user->setPassword($password);

   $role = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AcmeAccountBundle:Role')
                ->find(2); // Finds "ROLE_USER"
   $userRole = new UserRole();
   $userRole->setRole($role);

   $user->addUserRole($userRole);

   $em->persist($user);
   $em->flush();
   ```
7. Make sure you regenerate your schema, the most straight forward way of doing this is to run:

   ```
   $ php app/console doctrine:database:drop --force
   $ php app/console doctrine:database:create
   $ php app/console doctrine:schema:drop --force
   $ php app/console doctrine:schema:create
   $ php app/console doctrine:schema:validate
   ```

Comment: I will try it. It might work. But first I have to make working Doctrine2 extensions. I was trying to add them but it wrotes mi this:

Fatal error: Class 'Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener' not found in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/app/cache/prod/appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1377

I was googling and trying to solve the problem, no sucess. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It looks like you might have updated your bundles but have an older generated cache. Or you're not including a new dependency in composer. I would try updating all of the vendor bundles (Doctrine included) using the composer task and let it regenerate your cache. You may need to delete the cache manually.

Comment: I tried 'php composer.phar install' but no effect. I tried delete cache. It still doesn´t work.

Comment: So what to do with it?

Comment: You may want to try using the composer `update` command, `install` just uses the resolved dependencies in your `composer.lock` file, IIRC. Read more about composer's options here: http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md, also I run all my commands through the Symfony `console` script, you might try that as well (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/index.html)

Comment: The issue you're having with the `Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener` class on your classpath is really tangential to your current question and the proposed answer. If you're still having trouble with it, I would ask it as a separate question. The last bit of advice that I'll give in these comments regarding your issue is this: look through your configuration files (.xml and .yml) and see where the `Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener` class is being used. From there you can experiment, trying to find a solution for the issue.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will ask new question probably.

Comment: So I solved the problem with listeners. I tried to set the roles. Id doesn´t work. It wrotes that add method is not defined. I tried to edit it like this: **$role = new Role();
    $role->setName('User');
    $role->setRole('ROLE_USER');
    $user->getRoles()->add($role);** but nothing. Error: **Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() ** what to do with it?

Comment: And if I use the code you send, it wrotes: **Call to a member function add() on a non-object in /data/web/virtuals/48565/virtual/www/domains/kozusnikjan.com/Symfony/src/Acme/AccountBundle/Controller/AccountController.php on line 52**

Comment: See the above edit. I was under the misunderstanding that `getRoles()` returned the `ArrayCollection` not the primitive array.

Comment: I read it. Thank you. But I m not sure, how did you meaned it? What should I do now?

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t noticed the code you edited. But now it wrotes this:

Comment: **A new entity was found through the relationship 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User#roles' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Role@00000000307eabec000000005abf8582. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Role#__toString()' to get a clue.**

Comment: The above error message that you're getting has to do with the relationship between your user-and-role entities. Read the error message closely: "_to solve this issue: either explicityly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity **or configure cascade [to] persist this association**..._", you need to add cascade rules for your `@ManyToMany` mapping so that when you persist the `User` it will also save the roles, see: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#manytomany

Comment: But I think, that I have it done. In User.php line 51, in Role.php line 33

Comment: Your `User` class does not specify any sort of `cascade` option, see the above edit with the added source code that suggests a change to your `$roles` mapping to include **cascade={"all"}** which is the most liberal of all of the cascade options.

Comment: I did it as you wrote, but it is trying to wrote in into acme_roles table, where I save role types - admin, user .... but I want to save the role of user into user_roles table - I save there user id and role id.

Comment: Then you need to reconsider what you have mapped and how you map them. Currently your `User` entity references your roles as the `Role` entities maintained by the table `acme_roles`. If you want an intermediate table, e.g. `UserRoleAssociation` which maintains the relationship between a `User` object and a `Role` object based on the roles available to you in the `acme_roles` table you need to rethink your data model and accommodate for that. A quick search yields the following site with example code: http://codemonkeys.be/2013/02/example-of-a-doctrine-2-x-many-to-many-association-class/

Comment: I´m trying to help myself. I created UserRole file. I put new files into question. But it wrotes this: **Entity of type Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\UserRole is missing an assigned ID for field 'user_id'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.**  A little I know, where might be the problem but I don´t know how to solve it.

Comment: So if I understand you good, I will save user into database and than externally I will set him roles? I thought that it is possible to set it that it will save into database together with one query.

Comment: Ok, it is saving into database, but if I´m trying to login, it says me this:
**An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.user_id AS user_id1, t0.role_id AS role_id2 FROM user_role t0 INNER JOIN user_userrole ON t0.id = user_userrole.userrole_id WHERE user_userrole.user_id = ?' with params [34]:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'd48565_symfony.user_userrole' doesn't exist**

Comment: You can save the user, with the associated roles in one query. Yes. To do that you would use `cascades`, however if you want a small list of `roles` to assign references to, these need to be populated first so that you can get the reference to the proper role which you are attributing to the user. Then, upon saving the `User` it will cascade the `UserRole` to the database with all references intact.

Comment: Ok, and how can I do it and how can I solve the error which it wrotes? I´m so sorry, but it is driving me mad....

Comment: So I solved the error. It needs to replace this: 
`@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="UserRole", inversedBy="users", cascade={"all"})`  with this: `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")`
But now the tables user_role and acme_users aren´t mapped together and I can´t to save it with one query. Or yes?

Comment: Thank you. But if I tried to do it as you wrote, it wrotes me error: **Found entity of type Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\Role on association Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\User#roles, but expecting Acme\AccountBundle\Entity\UserRole** Role file I added into question

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40981/discussion-between-sean-quinn-and-jan-kozusnik)